# Diagnostic JavaScript to sniff image requests client side

Tags: javascript, tracking, ads, affiliate

**Background:**
We use [tracking pixels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) on our site to pass sales data to advertising networks we work with. Some nasty bug is resulting in bad data being recorded by our partners and we are looking for a way to diagnose. Server logs show that we are generating the correct < img > request and we're out of ideas to identify the cause of the bug...

**Question:** Is there a JavaScript method for sniffing the outbound client-side image requests made on our site? I.e., would it be possible to load a client-side JS that looks for image requests to a particular domain, records those requests and then sends that information to our server?

Comment: If server logs show that you are generating the correct requests for images, then surely that shows that the problem is on their end?

Comment: I would hope so, Jim! Didn't want to confuse things but there's a whole ton of complexity here. I'm actually serving these pixels using a 3rd party tag management SaaS provider which is generating the request using JSON I've exposed in my HTML. My logs show that the JSON is accurate but I still need to determine if the bug is downstream of my SaaS provider (i.e. with the data recipient), my fault or the SaaS provider's bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google Chrome's build in network panel. View->Developer->Developer Tools.

Comment: Yes, precisely. But I need to get the data that shows in the Chrome network panel or Firebug (really just a small part of it) for all visitors on my site.